# How to wrap resource title in fullCalendar timeline view when the divider is not moved yet?

Tags: css, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm using FullCalendar in React and the resource title is sometimes long. The user can move the divider when needed, but what I want is to wrap the resource title when it does not fit into the given space.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is simply to make the text wrap (it inherits a no-wrap rule from its parent elements by default):

```
.fc-cell-text
{
  white-space: normal;
}
```

To stop the text overflowing again if the divider is moved to make the resource name area smaller, you can also add an event listener to make fullCalendar update its size whenever the divider is clicked:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("fc-divider")) {
    console.log("here");
    calendar.updateSize();
  }
});
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/KKdjzoW

Comment: okay but when the text is wrapped it overflows the height of the resource, I was trying to set the height to auto by getting the element and then changing the style but it did not work. I was doing the following in the resource render function: info.el.childNodes[0].style.height = 'auto';

Comment: It doesn't overflow in my demo - did you look? The resource expands its height to accommodate it

Comment: when I first move the divider it overflows, but once I resize the window it adjusts the height. Is there a way of forcing the adjustment (recalculate layout) when the divider is moved?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand, why are you moving the divider? As my demo shows the problem is solved without needing to move anything

Comment: Now I have the following: when the user moves the divider, the resource text is wrapped but it overflows its container (even in your demo). but when you resize the window or do anything that makes the window resize, the calendar adjusts the width and it looks fine. What I'm looking for is how to force this adjustments when the divider is moved

Comment: Never mind. It worked; I added an event listener on clicking the divider, and called updateSize() function.

Comment: ok thanks, I get what you mean now. I'll that extra bit of advice to the answer and demo.